# Los valores traidos de la base de datos se repiten en el select

Tags: angular, ngfor

Estoy trabajando con Angular e intente llenar un select con datos que se encuentran almacenados en la BD. Pero esta informacion se repite, mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo mostrar en el select los valores sin que se repitan?

```
<div class="col-md-4 content-select1">
  <select name="" >
    <option *ngFor="let pm10 of pm10 ">{{pm10.estacion}}</option>
  </select>
  </div>
```

Gracias por la ayuda...

Comment: Pregunta para orientar la búsqueda de la respuesta: ¿es más fácil generar el conjunto de datos correcto desde la consulta? O es más fácil depurar eso en presentación? Yo tiendo a elegir la primera opción, pero para algunos proyectos puede ser al contrario.

Comment: Como esta tu consulta?, porque puedes aplicar un ```DISTINCT``` para traer datos no repetidos, y así no tienes que filtrarlos en front-end, ademas traerías datos innecesarios

Comment: Lo primero es saber si los datos vienen repetidos desde el servidor, por otro lado es importante que las variables `pm10` no tengan el mismo nombre, puede ajustar el `*ngFor` así: `<option *ngFor="let option of pm10">{{ option.estacion }}</option>`.